# action tag in a form didn't work out in google chrome

Tags: php

can anyone tell me why is that the action in the form tag is not working on google chrome?i use echo to display the the table and form..

i have this code..

```
echo "<form method='post' name='computation' action='savepagibigcomputation.php'>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>Blocknumber:</td><td class='reset_border_left'><b><label>$blocknumber</label></td>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='blocknumber' value='$blocknumber'>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>Lotnumber:</td><td><b><label>$lotnumber</label></td>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='lotnumber' value='$lotnumber'>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td colspan='5' align='right'><input type='submit' name='save' value='RESERVE' class='button'/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

so when i click the submit button the action should be excuted. In firefox is all working but in google chrome i really having a hard time to figure out why it will not re direct to the said action above??
any help is highly appreciated..
any one can help please..

Comment: I test it on my chrome and its working well???

Comment: For crying out loud, don't echo all that HTML out, just put it outside of `<?php ?>` (or use MVC).

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not well-formed. Your <input type="text"> tags end outside of table cells. Make sure your inputs are inside cells (<td> or <th>) of the <table>.

If something doesn't work, validating your HTML (in browser right click -> view source) with W3C HTML validator should be the first step in debugging, before trying to think what else could be wrong.

If fixing the HTML doesn't work, try looking at developer tools in Firefox (Firebug) or Chrome (Developer tools are integrated in Chrome) both at the DOM and the HTTP request the browser tries to make when you hit submit.

If it still doesn't work, you should provide us with a link so we don't have to guess (especially when your HTML is dynamic) what's wrong - we could instantly see what's wrong. For all we know, the issue might not even be in the code you posted, it could be a HTML formatting error somewhere else in <head> or <body>

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Chrome can mess with markup if there is an error in it. I suspect that the error is due to some other part of the code and not the part you have pasted here. Try this extract, it works on my chrome, this will rule out that element of your problem:

```
<?
$blocknumber = 1;
$lotnumber = 3;
echo "<form method='post' name='computation' action='savepagibigcomputation.php'>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>Blocknumber:</td><td class='reset_border_left'><b><label>$blocknumber</label></td>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='blocknumber' value='$blocknumber'>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>Lotnumber:</td><td><b><label>$lotnumber</label></td>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='lotnumber' value='$lotnumber'>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td colspan='5' align='right'><input type='submit' name='save' value='RESERVE' class='button'/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```